Azure Devops - How to pass database connection string as environment variable dynamically (azure cli)
Currently I'm using azure devops to deploy an app container to azure.
I've created my release pipeline and added each ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE within variable group.
In order to call the Environment variables dynamically, used below CLI commands in Azure CLI task
#!/bin/bash

# Initialize variable
ENV_VARS=""

# Loop through all environment variables
while IFS= read -r var
do
  # Check if the variable contains __ and starts with specific prefixes
  if [[ "$var" == APPSETTINGS__* || "$var" == AWSS3CONFIG__* || "$var" == CONNECTIONSTRINGS__* || "$var" == SMTPSETTINGS__* ]]; then
    # Extract the variable name and value
    name=$(echo "$var" | cut -d '=' -f 1 | sed 's/^//')
    value=$(echo "$var" | cut -d '=' -f 2-)

    if [[ "$value" == *" "* ]]; then
      value="\"$value\""
    fi

    # Append the variable and its value to the result
    ENV_VARS+="$name=$value "
  fi
done <<< "$(env)"

echo "Constructed envVars: $ENV_VARS"

# Example command using constructed envVars
az containerapp update \
            --name api-dev \
            --resource-group resource-group \
            --image dev.azurecr.io/api:$(Build.BuildId) \
            --set-env-vars "$ENV_VARS"


But, database connection string not set correctly and due to white space it consider as new key. e.g. User Id and Persist security info.

How to escape white space? Please help!
I've tried setting up value as double quote for variable stored in variable group and also directly in script too, but none of them work

Stupid question: do you really need to do this dynamically? It might give you some flexibility and eventually allow you to reuse the script for different scenarios, but on the other hand you need to be extra careful in order to handle encoding/escape special characters, etc.

You can pass environment variables in 3 ways..

Just setting them
export COOKIE=strawberry

Putting them in front of the program you are executing
COOKIE1=chocolate COOKIE2=peanuts bash -c 'set | grep COOKIE'

Or if you if you create a set of strings like you did, use 'eval'
eval 'export COOKIE1=coconut; export COOKIE2=oatmeal'
set | grep COOKIE



Thanks Ren Hoek, it works by eval as i was making string

You're welcome. If this answers your question, please mark this as your accepted solution.
